# How to Fix Simple Pester Unit Test

Tags: powershell, pester

I am new to pester and trying to run a very simple test on my workstation. However, it's failing and I am unsure as to why.

I've verified a string is returned and trimmed it for unseen whitespace. I've tested commands to ensure correct syntax. I am able to run a test with simple arithmetic operations successfully.

```
describe 'Verify Bios Version' {

    $bios = Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_bios 

    it 'the BIOS version value should be 1.1.4' {    
        $bios.SMBIOSBIOSVersion.Trim() | Should Be '1.1.4'
    }
 }
```

I expect this test to pass, but it shows as failed.

Comment: This passes for me (correcting for my BIOS version). What version of Pester are you using? I tried with both 3.4 and 4.7.3 and it seemed fine with both of those.

Comment: It would also help to see what Pester is returning, as the error usually indicates what mismatched the made the test fail. There's nothing syntactically wrong with your Pester test so its more than likely a mismatch between how the property is returned vs comparing it to a string.

Comment: As an aside, this isn't really a valid use of Pester.  Pester isn't for verifying system settings, etc, but rather to verify the behviour of _your_ code.  Unless you are the author of `Get-CimInstance` or the `Win32_Bios` class, then this test isn't really helping you in any way.

Comment: It’s fair to say it’s not the intended use of Pester, but plenty of people get value from using it to do infrastructure / environment validation.

Comment: Got it. Me being dumb. Mark, thank you for taking a look and replying.

boxdog, thanks for the reminder. Mark guessed it right that I'm an infrastructure guy. Code testing is my lesson for today...